# How can I add more feature for symfony2 sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

As title, I'm going to build a small project with symfony2 and sonata admin, but I dont know how to customize it.

Where can I get started to build a simple feature for sonata? any example, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below link provide SonataAdminBundle demo and good tutorial

demo: http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/dashboard

Tutorial: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle